# Pygame Sample length

Tags: pygame, raspberry-pi2

Currently I'm trying to build a Drumpad on my Raspberry PI 2.
Therefor I need a way to keep at least 16 samples loaded in the memory ready to be played.
I'm using the Pygame.mixer with which it works great for short samples, but longer sounds won't be played. The only thing I can hear is a clicking sound. There are a few people on the internet, reporting the same issue, but the only solution is using either .ogg or .wav (which I do).
So my question: Is there a limitation in size or length for the ***pygame.mixer.sound.play()*** command?
Or any other reason why it can only play short samples?

Comment: How long of sound clips are you looking to play? I use long (>4 min) .mp3 clips and don't have a problem.

Comment: The clips are max 20 secounds long...

Comment: ok and there is the same problem with .mp3

Comment: ...ok I figured that it probably is a totally different issue... the Rpi's soundcard. But I need to do some research on this...